# How to append/update new values to the rows of a existing csv file from a new csv file as a new column in python using pandas or something else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

> > Old file

Name, 2015

Jack, 205

Jill, 215

Joy, 369

> > New file

Name, 2016

Hill, 289

Jill, 501

Rauf, 631

Jack, 520

Kay, 236

Joy, 615

> > Here what i want:

Name, 2015, 2016

Jack, 205, 520

Jill, 215, 501

Joy, 369, 615

Hill, , 289

Rauf, , 631

Kay, , 236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for replying

I found a way as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

old_file = pd.read_csv('old file.csv')
new_file = pd.read_csv('new file.csv')

old_file = old_file[old_file['Name'].isna() == False]
new_file = new_file[new_file['Name'].isna() == False]

data_combined = pd.merge(old_file, new_file, left_on='Name', right_on='Name', how='outer')
print(data_combined.fillna(0).convert_dtypes())
```

This gives the desired output:

```
   Name  2015  2016
0  Jack   205   520
1  Jill   215   501
2   Joy   369   615
3  Hill     0   289
4  Rauf     0   631
5   Kay     0   236
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post about how to create a new column in Pandas DataFrame based on the existing columns:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-existing-columns/

It would help if you were to explain your bug in the following schema:

1. post your code
2. post your error or return code
3. post what you would have expected

Answer (score 0):

it took me a while to get this neat.

First of all you extract the values of the files:

```
    import csv
    
    with open('old.csv', 'r') as old_file:
        old_csv = [row for row in csv.reader(old_file)]
    with open('new.csv', 'r') as new_file:
        new_csv = [row for row in csv.reader(new_file)]
```

then we need to get the names of the new file:

```
    new_names = [row[0] for row in new_csv]
```

then we can iterate over all old rows so we can modify the new file and update the values

```
    for name, number in old_csv:
        index = None

        #Check if the name is already in the file
        if name in new_names:
            index = new_names.index(name)
            new_csv[index].append(number)
        
        #If not, add the new name with the number. This is maybe not neccessay
        else:
            new_entry = [name, number]
            new_csv.append(new_entry)
```

After we merged the lists, we write the new file

```
    with open('merged_file.csv', 'w') as merge_file:
        merger = csv.writer(merge_file)
        for row in new_csv:
            merger.writerow(row)
```

the File looks like this:

```
    Name, 2016, 2015
    Hill, 289
    Jill, 501, 215
    Rauf, 631
    Jack, 520, 205
    Kay, 236
    Joy, 615, 369
```

wasn't sure if "name" is the header or not. This need to be added in the csv reader